# Slideshow images duplicate in each time they shows

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I have image slideshow on main page [here](http://darbs.ecotechno.lv/)
I used this  [JsImgSlider](http://www.menucool.com/javascript-image-slider) for creating it. When I get to work it, it seems to on each new slide it loads the same image over and over. And also the transitions are pretty off the neccesary. They almost hang up or some delay hapens.
I am new at JS and jquery things, but when I open console I see this.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined application.js?body=1:13
GET http://darbs.ecotechno.lv/js/logging.js 404 (Not Found) (index):437
```

I thing this has nothing to do with my problem, I am right ?

Thanks!

Comment: JQuery is not linked properly, I see two jquery links to two different versions in your source code of the provided link.

Comment: @randomizer I removed first then refreshed page no change, then second and again no change

Comment: Do you put your code to $(document).ready function?